# Download just one port from the Ports Collection of FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, download, bsd-ports

On a fresh FreeBSD 11.2 machine, my `/usr/ports` folder is empty.

Running:

```
portsnap fetch extract
```

…as [discussed in the Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html) results in filling my `/usr/ports` with a gig of content.

If I only want one thing from the [Ports Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ports_collection), such as the [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database server, this huge download is a needless waste of network traffic, disk space, and time.

➥ Is there a way to download only a single port to install?

If not, is there a way to download only one subset of the Ports Collection? For example, get just the `databases` sub-collection so I end up with only a `/usr/ports/databases`?

Comment: This is generally impossible, because ports tend to have dependencies, which also have their dependencies, and all of these also use some port infrastructure. So it is pretty hard to figure out minimal slice of the whole tree that is sufficient to build given port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `extract`

You can't do it with `portsnap`. If you've already a snapshot (you downloaded it already) you can `extract` only parts of ports tree (`portsnap extract databases/postgresql11-server`), see `man portsnap`:

> ```
>  path         For extract command only, operate only on parts of the ports                                                             
>
>               tree starting with path.  (e.g. portsnap extract                                                                                  
>               sysutils/port would extract sysutils/portsman,                                                                                    
>               sysutils/portsnap, sysutils/portupgrade, etc.)
> ```

## `svn`

If you don't want fetch these big files you can use `svn` instead of `portsnap`:

```
svn checkout https://svn.freebsd.org/ports/head/databases/postgresql11-server
```

See the [relevant part of handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html#ports-using-subversion-method).

The `svn` is part of the base system (`/usr/bin/svnlite` - you can use an alias or replace `svn` to `svnlite`) so you don't have to install [devel/subversion](https://www.freshports.org/devel/subversion).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is simple.  It is in the very chapter of the *Handbook* that you are looking at.

You will need the ports tree installed, which the *Handbook* explains how to do.  It gives two ways, `portsnap` and checking out the tree (or even part of it, although cross-package dependencies militate against this) from source control.  (PC-BSD/TrueOS users use git instead of subversion.)

Change to the individual directory of the port/package desired, run `make fetch` to fetch the source archive(s), and run `make extract` to extract the contents.  You end up with the ports tree skeleton and only the files for that port present.

A fetch can also be performed at a higher level, such as `/usr/ports/databases`, as the *Handbook* explains in §4.5.1.1.

Comment: My Question is not about the `make`. My Question is about **the ports tree of 34,000 apps that takes up a gig**. I’m not interested in installing 34,000 apps. So I really don’t want to install a ports tree for 34,000 apps. I want to access the ports collection for only a single port, for the Postgres database server app, along with its few dependencies.

Comment: Then do not install 34,000 apps.  You've nowhere been told to, in any answer here or in the _Handbook_.  Installing the ports tree is not, of course, installing any of the applications.